# System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("%5B0%2C1%2C6%5D") failing to decode

Tags: c#, winforms, html-encode, httplistener

I am listing port 80 manually using HttpListener on windows forms .net 4.0
framework.

So when i get the content i get the following text on one of the parameters."%5B0%2C1%2C6%5D"
The request is coming from ios device.

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("%5B0%2C1%2C6%5D")
```

fails to decode.

decode should return "[0,1,6]"

http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ can decode it. 
If i use iis and .net 4.0 that can decode it too.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to `UrlDecode`, not `HtmlDecode`.

"%xx" are hexadecimal-encoded ASCII values, as per this document: http://www.w3.org/International/O-URL-code.html used to encode reserved or extended characters within URIs.

"HTML encoding" (or generally, SGML Entities) begin with an ampersand character, e.g. `&amp;` or `&lt;`.`

BTW, if you want to perform URL decoding/encoding or HTML decoding/encoding from a client application (e.g. WinForms or WPF) don't use `System.Web.*` because the `System.Web.dll` is not necessarily available on every system because of the .NET Client Profile (though this only applies up-to .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5 and later all come with `System.Web.dll`, see here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )

Comment: Thank you. Solved my issues all together. I assumed post data was html but i get it now.